# SPI returning my transmitted message

Tags: c, linux, spi

I have written the following code to try to poll a single axis gyro chip for values:

```
#include < stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])

static const char *device = "/dev/spidev0.0";
static uint8_t mode;
static uint32_t speed = 1000000;
static uint16_t delay = 1000;
static uint8_t bits = 8;

static void transfer(int fd)
{
   int ret;
   int i;
   uint8_t tx[6] = {0b00001000, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

   uint8_t check = 0x00;
   for (ret = 0; ret < 5; ret++)
      check += tx[ret];
   tx[5] = ~check;

   uint8_t rx[6] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

   struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
    .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
    .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
    .len = 6,
    .delay_usecs = delay,
    .speed_hz = speed,
    .bits_per_word = 8,
   };

   ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
   if (ret < 1)
       printf("can't send spi message\n");

   printf("the received data is: ");
   for (ret = 0; ret < ARRAY_SIZE(rx); ret++) {
      printf("%.2X ", rx[ret]);
   }

   printf("\n");

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int ret = 0;
   int fd;

   fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
   ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);

   if (ret == -1)
      printf("can't set spi mode\n");

   ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &mode);

   if (ret == -1)
      printf("can't get spi mode\n");

   ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);

   if (ret == -1)
      printf("can't set bits per word\n");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1)
       printf("can't get bits per word\n");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);

    if (ret == -1)
       printf("can't set max speed hz\n");

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1)
        printf("can't get max speed hz\n");

    while(1){
       transfer(fd);
       sleep(1);
    }

    close(fd);

    return ret;
}
```

However, the value that is received is identical to the value that I've sent. This is my first time using SPI and it's certainly possible that I've made a simple error, but I can't see it.

In case it's necessary, [here](http://www.siliconsensing.com/media/399839/CRG20-00-0100-110_9_PDF_SSS_-.pdf) is the datasheet for the chip I'm using.

EDIT:

To clarify, before doing the data transfer:

```
tx = {0x08, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xF7}
rx = {0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00}
```

After doing the data transfer:

```
tx = {0x08, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xF7}
rx = {0x08, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xF7}
```

What I expected after the transfer was:

```
rx = {0x81, 0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00, ~0x82}
```

Comment: Is your received data identical to `tx` or `rx`?

Comment: Returned data is `rx`

Comment: Restated my question because it was unclear.  Sorry.

Comment: The values in `rx` are identical to the values that are sent in `tx`. I think I'm sending `tx = {0x08, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xF7}` and then the `rx` buffer contains `{0x08, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xF7}` when it had been initially `{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00}`

Comment: I think you have the command wrong. You're asking it to do a `CBITA` test, and the device is responding that a `CBITA` test is in progress (as you'd expect).

Comment: But even if I don't have the CBITA test enabled I get back exactly what I've sent

Comment: Your expected reply does not match what you've requested the device to do. You're asking it to active the built in test, which it appears to be doing judging by the response. But, your expected reply has a message count of 2, and a next message type of 1 (Rate/Aux1).  You didn't ask for a Rate/Aux 1, the NMT in your transfer was 0.  Try setting your NMT to 1, or something else like the temperature sensor, and see what you get.